# SQL storage inside table

Tags: mysql

I need to store a sequence of SQL statements in one of my mySQL tables for "playback" at a later stage.  I sanitize, encrypt and base64 encode all user inputs.  A fairly typical statement to be recorded for playback would read something along the lines of

```
 INSERT INTO `skins` (sid,skid,skin) VALUES('nepi1sl3A','cici9vx4A','c') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE skin = 'c';
```

I pass this through a filter that changes it to

```
INSERT INTO `skins` (sid,skid,skin) VALUES(~nepi1sl3A~,~cici9vx4A~,~c~) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE skin = ~c~;
```

This makes playback easier since all I have to do at that stage is a *str_replace* for ~.

Given the encryption + base64 encoding the ~ character can never occur in any of the VALUES.

### Question - am I storing up any unforseen problems here.  If so is there a safer/better way of accomplishing the same thing?

After having read some of the comments * answers I felt a bit more clarification is due

Initially I was encrypting + base64 encoding the actual statement being stored for playback.  However, on reflection I felt that the need to base64 decode + decrypt prior to playback was imposing an unnecessary overhead since the original statement (with all user data sanitized, encrypted & base64 encoded) was not high risk anyway.  If I want to replace the quotes prior to storage it is to provide one final layer of security just in the,unlikely, event that one day I forget to do the sanitization/encryption/base64 encoding steps on user data.

Comment: Why not store them with the single quotes?  Sorry if I am being dense.

Comment: Quite apart from the fact that mySQL would throw a wobbly when given a quoted string within an InSERT statement I want to ensure a degree of security.  I scrupulously encrypt & base64 encode all user inputs but what if I miss something out now or at some future date? The single quote replacement provides a buffer against that.

Comment: Since you're base64-encoding, the quotes will be gone when you do the insert. So there's no need to do any string replacing.

Comment: Also, if you use an API that supports prepared statements, MySQl won't throw any wobblies when you try to insert values with quoted strings.

Comment: The quotes will be gone **inside** the VALUES bit of the SQL statement being stored.  But the statement itself would have single quotes. I know this sounds rather complicated. I am trying to store SQL inside a DB table for later execution so that sQL will contain pretty much what a normal SQL statement would - including quotes!

Comment: Right but you use bind values right?  Concatenating strings invites SQL injection and generally is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any fatal problems with what you're doing. As far as the database is concerned, this is just opaque data -- the fact that it represents SQL queries is irrelevant. If there's any danger, it would be based on where the SQL queries come from (e.g. user input); saving them in a table doesn't make it more or less dangerous.

As I mentioned in the comments, you don't need to replace the quotes in the statement. Quotes only cause a problem if you try to substitute the statement with quotes into a query. But since you're encoding the statement before substituting it into the query, the quotes will be gone.

Ideally you should be using an API with parametrized queries rather than substituting directly into `INSERT` statements. E.g. if you use PHP, you should use PDO or MySQLi.